# SQL substitution feature in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

Three or four years ago I read in an Oracle blog somewhere that a DBA had used for an emergency incident resolution an Oracle 10g feature of real time SQL substitution. Basically, he configured Oracle in way that every time that it received a certain query A it executed another query B instead. No application code change, no schema change, just a simple "execute query B instead of A" type of configuration.

Not that I am planning to use that feature (I can think of some undesirable consequences), but out of curiosity does it really exist? If yes, what is that feature called?

Comment: Stored outlines

Comment: Or SQL Profiles. See http://antognini.ch/papers/SQLProfiles_20060622.pdf and http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/outlines.php

Comment: @Phil: I thought stored outlines were only for execution plans. Is it possible to use them to substitute actual queries the way the OP describes?

Comment: Yes, you can change the SQL text using Outlines. I've done this before in 9i to modify a query to add a couple of hints. This shows how it is done: http://practicalappsdba.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/how-to-force-hints-using-outlines/ - I don't see why you can't change the query as long as the input & output remains the same  - outlines are evaluated & substituted at parse time

Comment: @Phil: Cool! Why not post an answer with an example?

Comment: Could also be a materialized view with query rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like the [DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_advrwr.htm#CFAGJHJB).  Tim Hall has an excellent walk-through of using that package to [point an application's queries against a different table or view](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_advanced_rewrite.php).

If you merely want to change the query plan but not point the query at a different table, you can use stored outlines or SQL profiles.

For example, I have tables `FOO` with 1 row and `BAR` with 2 rows

```
SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1
----------
         1

SQL> select * from bar;

      COL1
----------
        66
        77
```

I can declare a rewrite equivalence saying that queries against `FOO` should instead hit `BAR`

```
begin
  sys.DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE.DECLARE_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCE(
    'Rewrite_Foo',
    'select col1 from foo',
    'select col1 from bar',
    false,
    'TEXT_MATCH' );
end;
```

Now, if I set `query_rewrite_integrity` to trusted, queries against `FOO` end up hitting a completely different table.

```
SQL> alter session set query_rewrite_integrity=trusted;

Session altered.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1
----------
        66
        77
```

That can create some rather interesting query plans where the object you're querying is nowhere to be found in the plan

```
SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1
----------
        66
        77


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4224476444

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     2 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| BAR  |     2 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        584  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        523  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          2  rows processed
```